# Sum not performing addition on the list specified in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

So i've got the list, i've changed it from strings to integers and now i need to add them all up for a total. The only thing is, my code is not doing the calculation, even when the function is called. Here's my code;

```
    # create an empty list for your products.
products = []

# Asking for the number of elements to be inputted.
n = int(input("Enter number of products you're buying : "))

# Some UI for the customer.
print("What are these products?")
# iterating until the range that has been chosen.
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = input()

    products.append(" - " + ele)  # adding the element


def totalPrice():
    price = [int(cost[i])]
    print(sum(price))


# Some UI for the customer.
print("How much do those items cost?")
# create an empty list for your prices.
cost = []

# iterating until the range of the products array.
for i in range(products.__len__()):
    ele = str(input())

    cost.append(ele)  # adding the element

# concatenating the lists, putting them in descending order and displaying them.
newList = [i + j for i, j in zip(cost, products)]
newList.sort(reverse=True)
print("Your products are : " + str(newList))


totalPrice()
```

The function should change the 'cost' list of strings to integers in a new list and add them all together, if i try to target the index of the 'price' list, it gives mean an iteration error.
Do i need to specify addition? Am i using the wrong function?

Comment: please indent your code accordingly

Comment: Please fix your posted code to make sure it appears indented here exactly as it appears in your actual source files. You need an *extra* four spaces before *each* line of code, as compared to the original. You can do this by pasting, *selecting the entire code block*, and hitting the indent button.

Comment: Sorry guys, is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function,

```
price = [int(cost[i])]
```

This puts a *single* element into the list `price`, using the *global* value of `i` that was left over after that `for i in range(products.__len__()):` loop ran at the top level. (Incidentally, don't call `.__len__()` yourself - the built-in `len` is designed to do it for you - and [don't loop that way anyway](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html).)

> if i try to target the index of the 'price' list, it gives mean an iteration error.

I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

If you want to build a list of values corresponding to the original list, then you need to actually do that - either by iterating with a `for` loop, or using a comprehension:

```
price = [int(c) for c in cost]
```

Comment: Absolute genius! I had no idea i was only targeting a single element. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: I mean, it's not clear to me why you would expect otherwise... ?

Comment: Anyway, please see the link I edited in - forgot that the first time around.